# datepicker not working if it is inside a master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, datepicker, textbox

Can someone help me out. Really desperate to make it work. Here is my full master page code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>IslandGas</title>
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src ="/js/bootstrap.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" class="form-horizontal">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="AdminUpdatePanel" runat="server">

    <ContentTemplate>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a id="home" href="~/Admin/dash.aspx" runat="server" class="navbar-brand">Island Gas Admin</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main" style="height: 1px;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="products" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-wrench"></i>Products <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a id="A1" href="ViewProducts.aspx" runat="server"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i>View Products</a></li>
                            <li><a id="A2" href="AddNewProduct.aspx" runat="server"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i>Add a Product</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="suppliers" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-wrench"></i>Category <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a id="A29" href="ViewCategory.aspx" runat="server"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i>View Product Categories</a></li>
                            <li><a id="A6" href="AddCategory.aspx" runat="server"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i>Add Product Category</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="orders" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-table"></i>Customer Orders <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a id="A10" href="CustomerOrder.aspx" runat="server"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i>View Orders</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="reports" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-table"></i>Income Reports <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a id="A17" href="IncomeReports.aspx" runat="server"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i>Report</a></li>
                            <li><a id="A3" href="ReportCustomerTrack.aspx" runat="server"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i>Customer Track Report</a></li>
                            <li><a id="A7" href="ReportProducts.aspx" runat="server"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i>Products Report</a></li>

                            <li><a id="A9" href="ReportRegisteredCustomers.aspx" runat="server"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i>Registered Customer</a></li>
                            <li><a id="A4" href="ReportsGR.aspx" runat="server"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i>Return Goods Requests</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li><li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="A5" href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-table"></i>Audit Trail <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a id="A8" href="AuditTrail.aspx" runat="server"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i>View Audit Trail</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    <li id="user" runat="server" class="dropdown" visible="true">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                            <asp:Literal ID="ltUser" runat="server" Text="Administrator" /> <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <asp:linkbutton ID="linkLogout" runat="server" onclick="link_Logout_Click" CausesValidation="False" >[Log Out]</asp:linkbutton>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="page-header">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="title" runat="server" /></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="content" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>Made by <a href="#">Duhaylungsod, Paolo</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js") %>'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/js/bootstrap.min.js") %>'></script>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

i am trying to make datepicker work. i have found a good code and it works perfectly fine in pages w/o a master page, update panel, script manager etc.
head code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

content:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

      $('[id$=txtExpiry]').datepicker({ showAnim: 'slideDown' });

  });
```

textbox:

```
<div class ="form-group">
        <label class ="control-label col-lg-4"> Expiry Date</label> 
        <div class = "col-lg-8">  
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtExpiry" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

really really desperate to make this work. help me out please

Comment: In the first example you have the datepicker inside a `input` tag, and in the second example it is inside a `TextBox` tag. Perhaps this is the issue?

Comment: @user1438893 hi, will update it. it worked in my textbox (w/o masterpage)

Comment: What is the resulting `input` element in the failing case?  is the client-side `id` unique?  When the JavaScript code runs, what does the jQuery selector find?  Whether or not a Master Page is involved is of no concern to JavaScript, by the time it renders client-side there is just one DOM.

Comment: the working date picker shows a calendar when i click on the textbox. while here, it has no action. calendar is not shown. but has no error. its as if its not reading the script @David

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod: This is a good opportunity to familiarize yourself with some debugging tools then.  Since JavaScript runs client side, the *first* thing you should do is actually look at the client-side code.  That `asp:TextBox` doesn't mean anything in this context, you need to examine the `input` that is generated.  Additionally, you can debug the client-side code in the browser and see more specifically where/how it is failing.  "it's as if it's not reading the script" isn't really debugging, it's just randomly guessing.

Comment: Does your masterpage have in the head section the references for jquery?

Comment: @GuilhermeJSantos shown in the update sir

Comment: Do you use Bootstrap? Maybe you have a conflict.

Comment: yes with bootstrap. any way to fix this or do i have to let go of the bootstrap @GuilhermeJSantos

Comment: @David can you help me out sir? tried everything i could

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod: Looks like you're getting 404 errors, so the links to those `.css` and `.js` files aren't correct.  I suspect that `~` character is what's causing a problem there.  That's used for application-relative paths server-side, but it has no meaning in the actual URL.

Comment: crap. i think i need to let go of the master page to make it work

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" runat="server" class="form-control">
```

When server control with ID *datepicker* will be rendered in html the result  html element will automatically generated id which contains prefixes based on parent server controls from master page, i.e
id="ctl100_main_datepicker"

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

The jquery selector searches html element with ID equals to "datepicker".
You can use element css class as a selector:

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>

<asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" runat="server" class="datepicker form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: still not working. its working fine with my other webpage.

Comment: Do you see any javascript errors in browser console?

Comment: There are error _$(...).datepicker is not a function_ in console. This means that the second js script hasn't been fully loaded when datepicker plugin initialization was called.

Comment: Try 
`<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  });
  </script>`
Instead of 
```<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
      $(function () {
          $("#datepicker").datepicker();
      });
  </script>```

Comment: still no effect sir

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
<asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

to this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" runat="server" class="datepicker, form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

Note the extra class called "Datepicker" in addition to 'form-control'. This should allow jquery to find the form element and apply a datepicker to it

Comment: error is shown in the picture sir. has an error console. any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Your stylesheets and js files aren't loading. I suggest you look at that in addition to changing the line i pointed out!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

If you don't want to use a css selector and keep selecting by id, try this :

```
$('#<%= datepicker.ClientID %>').datepicker();
```

This way you will have the id generated by ASP.NET.

MasterPage gives another id for controls. See this reference http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs

Answer (score 0):

When you are using a master page, to avoid same id in a page, asp.net itself change the textbox id, actually it adds the name of placeholder to the id of your control.

> For Example:
>   TextBox with "txtExpiry" id, in a placeholder with "content" id, become: "content_txtExpiry" when it rendered.

so may javascripts and jquery codes can not find the input!
and the solution is defining the datepicker not using the class or old id, using the final rendered names as "content_txtExpiry" so change your code as:

> $('[id$=content_txtExpiry]').datepicker({ showAnim: 'slideDown' });